# Setting Button text through XML

Tags: android, button

I want to add a String `Rate ₹` as my `Button` text 
I tried using

```
<string name="Rs">\u20B9</string>
```

which is working fine. But I am confused about adding the text `Rate` .

```
       <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/Rs"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: are you change button text at runtime also...?

Comment: No. I'm not changing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<string name="Rs">Rate \u20B9</string>` This should work.

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
<string name="Rs">Rate \u20B9</string>
```